# Converting curl command to request.post

Tags: python, django, curl, python-requests, cloud-foundry

I have following curl command:

```
curl.exe -u sys_dcmsys:sys_******1 -d "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=Token_WindowsAuth" -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://abcd-i.company.com/token -k -i
```

And i am trying to do the same over python using requests:

```
payload = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'scope': 'Token_WindowsAuth'
    }
header = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
result = requests.post(
        https://abcd-i.company.com/token,
        auth=HTTPBasicAuth('sys_dcmsys', 'sys_******1'),
        data=payload,
        headers=header,
        verify=False)

res_obj = result.json()
Result = namedtuple('Result', ['access_token', 'expires_in'])
result = Result(
        res_obj['access_token'], res_obj['expires_in'])
expires_in = result.expires_in
access_token = result.access_token
```

i am able to get the result from command line. but when i tried with request.post its failing. it says :

```
ERR Starting new HTTPS connection (1): iamws-i.intel.com:443
2019-10-23T11:48:28.58+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR https://abcd-i.company.com:443 "POST /api/api/v1/token HTTP/1.1" 500 1208
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Internal Server Error: /isso/auth
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     response = get_response(request)
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/app/isso/views.py", line 75, in auth
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     res_obj = result.json()
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
2019-10-23T11:48:28.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 10.109.72.31 - - [23/Oct/2019:06:18:28 +0000] "GET /isso/auth HTTP/1.1" 500 27 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"
```

returned as result.text: on the website

```
{
access_token: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
token_type: "Bearer",
expires_in: 5400
}
```

can any one suggest me why my python post request is failing when printed as json? 
How to convert response.text to json object

Comment: Looks like a problem with the response. Could you please show all code?

Comment: …and the full error traceback.

Comment: @YuriiKarabas edited with more code

Comment: and added traceback @KlausD.

Comment: it shows internal server error, its not a problem from requests

Comment: The response is not what you expect it to be. You should check the status code and print the body of the response before calling `.json()`.

Comment: https://curl.trillworks.com/#python maybe this will help

Comment: updated question with response.text @KlausD.

Comment: The posted JSON is invalid. The keys must have double quotation marks around them. You might want to try to parse them with a YAML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some websites require encoded data. So, have you tried:

```
requests.post(..., data=json.dumps(payload), ...)
```

or, using the `json` parameter:

```
requests.post(..., json=payload, ...)
```

In the latter case, payload will be automatically encoded.